# tools to generate entities from tables of db with out eclipse

Tags: java

I have to generate entities of tables. Through eclipse we can do but in our application, the end user has to generate & upload the entities as a file. So we need to integrate third party tools in the application.

Comment: May be you can write it in no time, you don't have to automate all database statements. It's only create table with all data types. Moreover you will have full control on your code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "generate entities"? Do you mean: generate JPA entity source files? This does not sound like something you would want the end user to do. Or do you mean something else?